# How to unmount (safely remove) USB disk/pendrive from Windows 8 after opening file in Metro Application

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, modern-ui, safely-remove-hardware

I have problem with unmounting (safely removal) of disk/pendrive from Windows 8 after opening some files from Metro application:

1. Attach disk
2. Open file (say photo) from Metro Application
3. Move to different screen in Metro Application
4. Change to desktop
5. Select safely remove device
6. I am prompted that I need to close an application before safely removing device. However I have no way of actually closing Metro Application from what I understend

What am I doing wrong? I found in documentation only how to attach disk not the recommended way of detaching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can*** in fact close Metro applications.

To do so, move the mouse to the top-middle of the screen. The cursor should turn into a "hand". Click and hold the left mouse button and drag down to the bottom left hand corner of the screen and let go. The app should now be closed.

The Windows 8 "Modern UI" is a mess in my own opinion. I've already had Windows virtually unusable from an app and the UI is appalling because of its lack of visual clues. The only way to recover was to run a PowerShell script created by someone in Microsoft! So I no longer use Metro apps.